# trigger to sum all elements for each camp

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have 3 tables pharmacy, have and meds

pharmacy:

```
id_pharm        name
   1           pharm1
   2           pharm2  
   3           pharm3
   4           pharm4
   5           pharm5
```

have

```
fk_id_pharm     amount    fk_id_med
1                40           2
1                 1           3
2                45           1
2                20           4
3                10           1
3                45           3
```

meds

```
  id_med            name       
    1               med1
    2               med2
    3               med3
    4               med4
    5               med5
```

I need to calculate a computed column with a trigger that give me the sum of the amount of all pharmacies so I think I need something like this

```
 id_med            name          stock   
    1               med1          55      --(45 + 10)
    2               med2          40      
    3               med3          46      --(45 + 1)
    4               med4          20
    5               med5          0
```

my trigger try

```
ALTER TABLE meds ADD COLUMN stock INT DEFAULT 0;

DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER `trigger3`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `have` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE meds SET stock = (SELECT SUM(have.amount) FROM have INNER JOIN meds ON have.fk_id_med=meds.id_med GROUP BY meds.name);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

but when I try to do a insert in have

```
insert into have (fk_pharm_id, amount, fk_med_id) values (5,80,5)
```

I got this:

`You can't specify target table 'meds' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trig_have_insert
AFTER INSERT ON `have`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE meds
        SET stock = meds.stock + NEW.amount
        WHERE meds.id_med = NEW.fk_id_med;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Something is wrong with a trigger that does not refer to `NEW` or `OLD` -- the values in the row being modified.  I am guessing this is what you want.